# AJAX, POST, JSON, and PHP: How do I do it?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, post

How do I send AJAX data through $.ajax() in JavaScript via type: "POST" using JSON data formatting and how do I receive the data in a PHP script (through $_POST??) and put it into an array so I can use it?  I've been kicking at this for hours and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  If someone could post the JS and PHP code for sending and receiving JSON formatted data, I would be eternally grateful!!!!!

JS Code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(location).attr('protocol') + "//" + $(location).attr('hostname') + "/ajax/rate.php",
                data: {
                    "value1": 1,
                    "value2": 2,
                    "value3": 3,
                    "value4": 4,
                    "value5": 5
                },
                dataType: "json"
            });
```

PHP Code:

I was just using $_POST["value1"], etc., to get that value.  On that note, is there a way to make the ajax request GET instead AND open up a new window with that GET data on it so I can see what's going on??

Comment: Did you Google for "JSON PHP examples"?  Did none of the hits help?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: No idea what you're doing wrong or no idea what you're doing? I'd suggest posting up samples of codes you have so far, there is oodles of documentation out there on what I'm assuming you're using jquery and php's json encode/decode functionality.

Comment: There's plenty of examples on the jquery site. What's more important is that you can correctly use a debugger. Checkout Opera Dragonfly, Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's developer tools - you can see what's being called, what gets returned. Then investigate the examples. Then make them yourself, with static files. Then generate the files dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to create a php page the outputs data in JSON form. This data is taken from an array and echoed using the `json_encode` function. Using the `$.ajax()` method from jQuery, you send a request to that page and manipulate the data in the `success:` function.

Example.

PHP - array.php

```
$array = ("flag" => 1); 
echo json_encode($array);
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
  url : '/array.php', // page containing JSON data
  dataType : 'json', // must be specified for JSON manipulation in success
  success : function(data) { 
       // this function is called if the call to test.php is successful
       // access the data using object dot syntax
       alert(data.flag); // should display '1'
  }
});
```

// Send data to server this way
PHP - test.php

```
echo $_POST['data'];
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
  url : '/test.php',
  dataType : 'text', 
  type : 'post',
  data : { data : 'Hello, World!'},
  success : function(data)          
       alert(data); // should display 'Hello, World'
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay, check my 2nd example.  In the data property, place the JSON data. Use the `$_POST` keys to access the data within.

Comment: OMG, thank you soooo much!  That success function made me find out what I was doing wrong! >.<  Thanks a ton!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't POST data in a JSON format. Only as a query string, like GET. You can however return data from the PHP script in a JSON format.

Eg.

```
$.ajax({
 url: "script.php",
 dataType: 'json', // Tell jQuery/JS that the returned data from script.php is JSON format
 data: 'id='+Id, // will become $_POST['id'] with the value of Id (js var)
 success: function(data){
    // data is JSON formatted
 }
```

Now, in your PHP script, you receive a POST variable called $_POST['id'].
Let's say that $_POST['id'] is needed to request a certain customer from the database. Its data can be stored in an array and then json encoded and then send back to the page with the ajax request.